# Power amplification of pulse signal using Class D power amplifier

Tags: pwm, class-d

I want to amplify the power of a pulse signal with 55% duty cycle, generated using 555 timer, to 40 W. I am planning to use a class D amplifier. But I have the following doubts:

1. Can I directly apply my pulse signal to the gate driver of power MOSFETs? Since everywhere I have seen class D using PWM signal?
2. If no, how to generate PWM signal for my pulse signal?

I have an inductive load to drive.
[image: Attached is the pulse signal I want to amplify]

Comment: What is the FREQUENCY of your pulse signal?

Comment: Hi, frequency is 5kHz pulse signal with 55%duty cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the PWM signal from your modulator is exactly what you want to control your Class D output stage. However, depending on the exact Class D topology/IC, it can be that:

- you can directly feed the PWM into the half-bridge driver IC, which takes care of generating the complementary FET gate drive signals, level shifting, dead timing
- you have to feed in two signals for the top and bottom FET separately, in which case you have to make a circuit to create the complementary signals. In addition, dead timing can be integrated in the half-bridge driver or not. Read the data sheet.
- If you use two independent drivers for each of the FETs, you will surely have to take care of dead timing and level shifting yourself.